# VBA run code until the last row of a column range

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, dynamic

My code successfully works out where my last row of code is however gives a run-time error 1004 when it reaches setting the data range, but i want the code to run until the last row in my range. Does anyone know how to fix my code?

```
Sub PopulatingArrayVariable()

Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim x As Long
Dim TotalTargets As Double
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

TotalTargets = WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("D"))

Set DataRange = Sheets("Result").Range("D:I" & lastrow)

For Each cell In DataRange.Cells
    ReDim Preserve myArray(x)
    myArray(x) = cell.Value
    x = x + 1
Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

misstype here:

```
Set DataRange = Sheets("Result").Range("D:I" & lastrow)
```

should be

```
Set DataRange = Sheets("Result").Range("D1:I" & lastrow)
```

or Dx where x is your first line.